# systemfit Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object not found

Tags: r, systemfit

I am trying to use the systemfit package to estimate an econometric model. I keep on getting the `error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'gdp_gro' not found`. The thing is `gdp_gro` is definitely in my dataset.

I tried to Google this error, but I couldn't figure out the solution. Based on other questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere I think the issue lies with the way R handles formula environments. I would appreciate some guidance on why my code doesn't work and how to fix it. Thank you very much.

I am attaching a reprex and a partial data set (below):

```
library(systemfit)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: car
#> Loading required package: carData
#> Loading required package: lmtest
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> 
#> Please cite the 'systemfit' package as:
#> Arne Henningsen and Jeff D. Hamann (2007). systemfit: A Package for Estimating Systems of Simultaneous Equations in R. Journal of Statistical Software 23(4), 1-40. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v23/i04/.
#> 
#> If you have questions, suggestions, or comments regarding the 'systemfit' package, please use a forum or 'tracker' at systemfit's R-Forge site:
#> https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/systemfit/

#Prepare a new list
DF = list()

#Splitting the data in list elements by years
for (i in seq(from = 1, by =1, to =length(unique(as.numeric(df$year))))){

  DF[[i]] <- df[df$year == unique(as.numeric(df$year))[i],]

}
#> Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Equation = list()
Inststruments = list()

#### SPECIFCIATION OF EQUATIONS
for (i in seq(from = 1, by =1, to =length(unique(as.numeric(df$year))))){

  #Automatically pick up the instruments
  instruments <- select_vars(colnames(as.data.frame(DF[i])), ends_with("_I", ignore.case = FALSE))

  #Variables picked out automatically
  variables <- colnames(as.data.frame(DF[i]))[!colnames(as.data.frame(DF[i])) %in% c(instruments, "gdp_gro")]

  #Automatizing the equation specification 
  Equation[[i]] <- with(DF[i] , as.formula(paste("gdp_gro ~ ", paste(variables, collapse="+"))) )

  Inststruments[[i]] <- with(DF[i] , as.formula(paste("~ ", paste(instruments, collapse="+"))) )

}
#> Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

#Finally run the key regressions
reg <- systemfit(Equation, method = "3SLS", inst = Inststruments, methodResidCov = "noDfCor" )
#> Error in formula[[i]]: subscript out of bounds
```

Partial data (generated with dput):

```
  structure(list(country_code = c("AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUT", 
"AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", "BGR", "BGR", 
"BGR", "BGR"), year = c(1995L, 2000L, 2005L, 2010L, 1995L, 2000L, 
2005L, 2010L, 1995L, 2000L, 2005L, 2010L, 1995L, 2000L, 2005L, 
2010L), tot_lif = c(0.0128486367909746, 0.0126208212768577, 0.0123698898778096, 
0.0122406329302881, 0.0130432016288096, 0.0127997002997003, 0.0126053003750845, 
0.0124099521762818, 0.0130139312547017, 0.0128663779576979, 0.0126613550738064, 
0.0124714828897338, 0.0140739189685534, 0.0139541215710299, 0.013781512605042, 
0.0136031851360319), cap_aset = c(NA, 6.9, 6.9, 5.43, NA, 5.2, 
4.8, 7.49276, NA, 2.8, 2.7, 4.96531, NA, 15.3, 7.4, 10.4677), 
    cb_assets = c(3.06318, 2.46202, 2.20076, 3.33956, 0.399895, 
    0.536933, 0.551538, 0.815212, 0.972776, 0.466959, 0.248117, 
    0.823367, 7.90828, 8.51751, 3.15831, 0.095416), tot_fert = c(1.822, 
    1.756, 1.807, 1.928, 1.42, 1.36, 1.41, 1.44, 1.56, 1.67, 
    1.76, 1.86, 1.23, 1.26, 1.37, 1.57), nat_res = c(2.09714172369929, 
    3.51179102271941, 7.72238072354596, 8.01628506180971, 0.11853075155191, 
    0.150961988690622, 0.206953989580903, 0.216777594515187, 
    0.0223053533152314, 0.0203362079028292, 0.0177518400351335, 
    0.019336002220052, 1.47167055527445, 1.33790542432826, 2.31972541945117, 
    2.08046786610067), trad_term = c(NA, 100, 131.0849232, 178.9001645, 
    NA, 100, 95.91930131, 92.25883781, NA, 100, 98.77006835, 
    96.59919868, NA, 100, 84.20837461, 125.8550667), gov_cons = c(0.1471103005, 
    0.1474746565, 0.151790273666667, NA, 0.149812934333333, 0.154511682833333, 
    0.1511594605, NA, 0.171062330333333, 0.180379932166667, 0.174480045833333, 
    NA, 0.289015879333333, 0.323738674333333, 0.276189208166667, 
    NA), gdp_gro = c(3.8293687531652, 3.94318908229896, 3.19031634041626, 
    2.05294200395332, 2.66798366552709, 3.37572197324998, 2.24406681223554, 
    1.83709459152502, 2.3847572377606, 3.63365201492995, 2.09427270847185, 
    2.74421327182894, 2.86018944148833, 4.94055377635733, 7.12351107638302, 
    1.32408780093829), gross_inv = c(0.266632934333333, 0.260118643666667, 
    0.300801128, 0.264703502, 0.335587352333333, 0.260061338333333, 
    0.270549208, 0.287363499333333, 0.2805128, 0.246921166666667, 
    0.308350493333333, 0.324811398666667, 0.0818940103333333, 
    0.136577869666667, 0.236514484, 0.19643417), gdp_cap_1 = c(0.00192864730372135, 
    0.00222430451645368, 0.00250264618548625, 0.00273814839048662, 
    0.0027345490098763, 0.0032819778735874, 0.00334421790851598, 
    0.0037646138629738, NA, 0.00344158786452203, 0.00350312141684792, 
    0.00395886153650055, 0.000862928006781417, 0.000734707837639529, 
    0.000935582564325206, 0.0013229694175178), gdp_cap_2 = c(0.00191622588648934, 
    0.00221469960943122, 0.00254717484680898, 0.00285420952389829, 
    0.00252904621475959, 0.00305993171114882, 0.00329798344078102, 
    0.00354070266940731, NA, 0.00289716367632824, 0.00329402073984151, 
    0.00365521257262544, 0.000834744862348611, 0.000765775240349386, 
    0.000991473707456532, 0.0012880711598984), econ_open = c(1.11564470333333, 
    1.07036188216667, 1.31764187416667, NA, 1.19112350533333, 
    1.13605700933333, 1.37068624266667, NA, 1.14728215333333, 
    1.1020498675, 1.34182663783333, NA, 1.01287280516667, 0.982563148, 
    1.2535847325, NA), demo_2 = c(0.0156360833333333, NA, NA, 
    0.0272981816666667, 0.0162439233333333, 0.016152265, 0.0163356866666667, 
    0.0192567566666667, 0.0179158466666667, 0.02126817, 0.023894505, 
    0.0293736833333333, NA, 0.05795811, 0.0639238566666667, 0.052836915
    ), male_edu_1 = c(5.81, 5.82, 5.84, 5.87, 4.09, 3.86, 3.86, 
    3.87, 5.53, 5.59, 5.63, 5.59, 5.38, 5.43, 5.9, 6.3), male_edu_2 = c(4.78, 
    4.76, 4.81, 4.61, 5.48, 5.77, 6.08, 6.28, 3.79, 3.96, 4.31, 
    4.38, 2.87, 3.11, 3.72, 4.31), male_edu_3 = c(0.88, 0.78, 
    0.93, 1.12, 0.35, 0.48, 0.64, 0.71, 0.8, 0.88, 0.95, 1.05, 
    0.53, 0.58, 0.61, 0.71), male_edu_4 = c(11.48, 11.35, 11.58, 
    11.6, 9.92, 10.11, 10.58, 10.86, 10.12, 10.43, 10.88, 11.02, 
    8.79, 9.13, 10.23, 11.32), tot_lif_I = c(0.0128682464785598, 
    0.0127095722174518, 0.012465515344814, 0.0122834370967119, 
    0.0131404621173837, 0.0128830665052315, 0.012685638515979, 
    0.0124510515974525, 0.0130783197148458, 0.0129052789260619, 
    0.0127617321099324, 0.0125262669490894, 0.0140154543995514, 
    0.0140966755510497, 0.0138573536026272, 0.0136964325672041
    ), tot_fert_I = c(1.822, 1.756, 1.807, 1.928, 1.42, 1.36, 
    1.41, 1.44, 1.56, 1.67, 1.76, 1.86, 1.23, 1.26, 1.37, 1.57
    ), gov_cons_I = c(0.147556354666667, 0.147787615333333, 0.14822341, 
    0.154233063333333, 0.143237327333333, 0.154914428666667, 
    0.150818939, 0.160776774333333, 0.167895371666667, 0.174698651, 
    0.174371118333333, 0.185355464666667, 0.318261792333333, 
    0.319208641666667, 0.313319266, 0.274927805), gross_inv_I = c(0.271324028333333, 
    0.263693382333333, 0.298435052333333, 0.269873092666667, 
    0.342670599333333, 0.287529100666667, 0.262940883333333, 
    0.273333341, 0.290991584333333, 0.259098499666667, 0.269275173666667, 
    0.313822090666667, 0.0746616733333333, 0.12165235, 0.171543354666667, 
    0.245303109333333), gdp_cap_1_I = c(0.00192864730372135, 
    0.00222430451645368, 0.00250264618548625, 0.00273814839048662, 
    0.0027345490098763, 0.0032819778735874, 0.00334421790851598, 
    0.0037646138629738, NA, 0.00344158786452203, 0.00350312141684792, 
    0.00395886153650055, 0.000862928006781417, 0.000734707837639529, 
    0.000935582564325206, 0.0013229694175178), gdp_cap_2_I = c(0.00191622588648934, 
    0.00221469960943122, 0.00254717484680898, 0.00285420952389829, 
    0.00252904621475959, 0.00305993171114882, 0.00329798344078102, 
    0.00354070266940731, NA, 0.00289716367632824, 0.00329402073984151, 
    0.00365521257262544, 0.000834744862348611, 0.000765775240349386, 
    0.000991473707456532, 0.0012880711598984), econ_open_I = c(1.08680443966667, 
    1.05545339966667, 1.146271606, 1.401552578, 1.17984314766667, 
    1.122572442, 1.21375773333333, 1.43774867033333, 1.14471817, 
    1.08343706533333, 1.18125647333333, 1.41352349533333, 1.00123712466667, 
    0.956378658666667, 1.057932824, 1.33654979833333), demo_2_I = c(0.0174405, 
    0.0141582, NA, 0.02649142, 0.01485111, 0.01894116, 0.01685453, 
    0.01725761, 0.01650168, 0.01752877, 0.02481076, 0.02306411, 
    0.0366033, 0.0530792, 0.06323963, 0.05811036)), row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the packages developer and thanks to his efforts my problem is resolved in systemfit 1.1-23. This version is not yet availible on CRAN, but can be obtained from R-Forge: http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=242 or using the command:

```
install.packages("systemfit",repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the data argument to systemfit and also run the function on the individual items of the lists.

```
reg <- systemfit::systemfit(Equation[[1]], method = "3SLS", inst = Inststruments[[1]], 
methodResidCov = "noDfCor", data = DF[[1]])
> Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
   index larger than maximal 0
```

This fixes your first problem but then gives you another :)

Comment: I tried that. The thing is for 3SLS you need to pass a system of equations, so I one should add: “data= DF”. When I do this it get the same error as described above.

Comment: hmm. While tracking down the error with browser() i might have found a bug. In the function .prepareData.systemfit, there is a matchcall to "data" which, gives an error since formula cannot find the target variable in a list. Manually changing the line to "data[[1]]" makes the code continue. Maybe you should submit a bug on the github page? (line 6 of https://github.com/cran/systemfit/blob/master/R/prepareData.R)